# Parse app crashes after pressing "OK" on Push Notification Alert

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, ios9

I don't have any code handling or creating a new UIAlertView in my didReceiveRemoteNotification method. Simply..

```
PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
  print("active")
}
```

When I press "OK" on the alert, the app crashes with exec_bad_access and the stack is stuck on the completion(NSNotFound) line below.

```
 if ([UIAlertController class] != nil) {
    __block UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                                     message:message
                                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    void (^alertActionHandler)(UIAlertAction *) = [^(UIAlertAction *action){
        // This block intentionally retains alertController, and releases it afterwards.
        if (action.style == UIAlertActionStyleCancel) {
            completion(NSNotFound);
        } else {
            NSUInteger index = [alertController.actions indexOfObject:action];
            completion(index - 1);
        }
        alertController = nil;
    } copy];
```

Comment: I faced the same problem as you. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: I believe Parse fixed this in 1.8.5

Comment: Yes. They fixed it in the latest sdk. [link](https://parse.com/docs/downloads)